# How to install Berkeley DB for SICstus on Windows?

Tags: sicstus-prolog

This maybe a dumb question but can someone explain how to install Berkeley for SICstus on Windows? This is my last resort

Answer (score 2):

The entire Oracle site for [Berkeley DB](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/related/berkeleydb-downloads.html) seems broken, with many broken links. Also, there are no longer any installers, and only the latest version of the source code. Their site has been that way for over a year. I do not know what happened.

In the mean time, I was able to download the Windows installers by first creating a free Oracle Account, logging in, and then using the links https://download.oracle.com/otn/berkeley-db/db-6.2.38_64.msi and https://download.oracle.com/otn/berkeley-db/db-6.2.38_86.msi (found via the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200520095439/https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/related/berkeleydb-release-history.html)). These versions should be compatible with SICStus Prolog 4.6 on Windows.

Comment: Obviously these problems means that you should avoid depending on the SICStus Prolog Berkeley DB library, if possible. In the next version of SICStus we plan to add a new library with similar functionality, based on another database technology.

Comment: Thanks for the help I've looked at the ODBC library but Berkeley currently was more suitable. Looking forward to the new library in the next version.